# Sample size for multiple demographic factors (non-probabilistic)

Tags: statistical-significance, sample-size

I'm trying to work out the minimum useful sample size for a survey that will attempt to find out which of 13 demographic factors (such as educational background) influences the respondents' views on a series of topics related to nature conservation (non-probabilistic sampling, findings will only apply to our sample). Each of the 13 demographic factors has between 3 and 9 variants (for example, 'age' is split into 6 ranges). Data analysis: Principal Component Analysis. Dependent variables are quantitative scores along to orthogonal axes. How can I calculate how many responses we need to be able to work out which factors are important in shaping people's views? Surely it is not just the total number of respondents, but how they are distributed amongst the factors and variants that matters? How can I take this into account when calculating the sample size that we should aim for? Thanks!

Comment: You may want to add what approach you intend to take to analyse the data (e.g., multiple regression) and what types (and how many) dependent variables you have.

Comment: Thanks. There are two dependent variables, which are the positions along two orthogonal axes along which the respondents' answers are weighted. The plan is to then use PCA to see if different groups form separate clusters on the graph